# Kendall tau distance (a.k.a bubble-sort distance) between permutations in base R

Tags: r, algorithm, permutation

How can the Kendall tau distance (a.k.a. bubble-sort distance) between two permutations be calculated in R without loading additional libraries?

Comment: Do you have the algorithm in either math or pseudocode to help us out?

Comment: I wonder if you could adapt the results of `cov(x,y,method="kendall")` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an O(n.log(n)) implementation scraped together after reading around, but I suspect there may be better R solutions.

```
inversionNumber <- function(x){
    mergeSort <- function(x){
        if(length(x) == 1){
            inv <- 0
            #printind(' base case')
        } else {
            n <- length(x)
            n1 <- ceiling(n/2)
            n2 <- n-n1
            y1 <- mergeSort(x[1:n1])
            y2 <- mergeSort(x[n1+1:n2])
            inv <- y1$inversions + y2$inversions
            x1 <- y1$sortedVector
            x2 <- y2$sortedVector
            i1 <- 1
            i2 <- 1
            while(i1+i2 <= n1+n2+1){
                if(i2 > n2 || (i1 <= n1 && x1[i1] <= x2[i2])){ # ***
                    x[i1+i2-1] <- x1[i1]
                    i1 <- i1 + 1
                } else {
                    inv <- inv + n1 + 1 - i1
                    x[i1+i2-1] <- x2[i2]
                    i2 <- i2 + 1
                }
            }
        }
        return (list(inversions=inv,sortedVector=x))
    }
    r <- mergeSort(x)
    return (r$inversions)
}
```

.

```
kendallTauDistance <- function(x,y){
    return(inversionNumber(order(x)[rank(y)]))
}
```

If one needs custom tie-breaking one would have to fiddle with the last condition on the line marked `# ***`

Usage:

```
> kendallTauDistance(c(1,2,4,3),c(2,3,1,4))
[1] 3
```

Comment: Looks pretty clean w/ one comment: you should put parenthesis in the while/if conditional to be crystal clear about the precedence of `||` and `&&` )

Comment: @Carl Thanks! ((I dislike redundant parentheses but) ok then.)

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm. Somebody is interested in exactly same thing which I have been working on.

Below is my code in python.

```
from collections import OrderedDict


def invert(u):
    identity = sorted(u)
    ui = []
    for x in identity:
        index = u.index(x)
        ui.append(identity[index])
    print "Given U is:\n",u
    print "Inverse of U is:\n",ui
    return identity,ui

def r_vector(x,y,id):
    # from collections import OrderedDict
    id_x_Map = OrderedDict(zip(id,x))
    id_y_Map = OrderedDict(zip(id,y))
    r = []
    for x_index,x_value in id_x_Map.items():
        for y_index,y_value in id_y_Map.items():
            if (x_value == y_index):
                r.append(y_value)

    print r
    return r

def xr_vector(x):
    # from collections import OrderedDict
    values_checked = []
    unorderd_xr = []
    ordered_xr = []

    for value in x:
        values_to_right = []
        for n in x[x.index(value)+1:]:
                    values_to_right.append(n)
            result = [i for i in values_to_right if i < value]
            if(len(result)!=0):
                values_checked.append(value)
                unorderd_xr.append(len(result))

    value_ltValuePair = OrderedDict(zip(values_checked,unorderd_xr))

    for key in sorted(value_ltValuePair):
        # print key,value_ltValuePair[key]
        ordered_xr.append(value_ltValuePair[key])
    print "Xr= ",ordered_xr
    print "Kendal Tau distance = ",sum(ordered_xr)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "***********************************************************"
    print "Enter the first string (U):"
    u = raw_input().split() 
    print "Enter the second string (V):"
    v = raw_input().split()
    print "***********************************************************"

    print "Step 1: Find U Inverse"
    identity,uinverse = invert(u)
    print "***********************************************************"

    print "Step 2: Find R = V.UInverse"
    r = r_vector(v,uinverse,identity)
    print "***********************************************************"

    print "Step 3: Finding XR and Kenday_Tau"
    xr_vector(r)
```

About the approach/ algorithm to find Kendall Tau distance this way, I would either leave it to you, or point towards the research paper **[Optimal Permutation Codes and the Kendall’s τ-Metric](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.4963v1)**

You can implement (Approach) the same in R.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
(choose(length(x),2) - cov(x,y,method='kendall')/2)/2
```

if you know that both of the input lists `x` and `y` do not contain duplicates.